# the executorService throw RejectException with SynchronousQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I want to make a boundedExecutor, only a fixed number thread can be executed parallel. when more task added, the executor will block until other threads complete.

here is the Executor I found in other questions.

```
public class BoundedExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BoundedExecutor.class);
    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public BoundedExecutor(int bound){
        super(bound, bound, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());
        this.semaphore = new Semaphore(bound);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable task) {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            super.execute(task);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("interruptedException while acquiring semaphore");
        }
    }

    protected void afterExecute(final Runnable task, final Throwable t){
        super.afterExecute(task, t);
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

and the main code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Runnable task = () -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " complete.");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        BoundedExecutor pool = new BoundedExecutor(1);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            pool.execute(task);
        }
        pool.shutdown();
    }
```

I thought the code made a single thread and will execute tasks sequentially, but actually, when first task complete, the executor thrown java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException.

as I undersdood, the semaphore.acquire() will block the thread until the first task complete and release the semaphore, what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Why are you using a Semaphore with a SynchronousQueue?  What are you trying achieve by doing this?

Comment: the semaphore is used for blocking the ThreadExecutor  add new task, when the pool is fulled.
the synchronousQueue is used, because I don't want to queue the task, when pool is fulled.

Comment: So using a SynchronousQueue will block whenever there is not a free thread to pick it up, so what does the Semaphore add to this?

Comment: No, SynchronousQueue will not block, the ThreadPoolExecutor used workerQueue.offer(command) to put element, it will return false immediately  in synchronousQueue in general, so in order to keep the blocking state, semaphore is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make the Queue block and not use a Semaphore

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SynchronousQueue<Runnable> queue = new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean offer(Runnable runnable) {
            try {
                return super.offer(runnable, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, queue);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int finalI = i;
        pool.execute(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(LocalTime.now() + " - " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + finalI + " complete");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    pool.shutdown();
}
```

prints

```
13:24:14.241 - pool-1-thread-1 0 complete
13:24:15.247 - pool-1-thread-1 1 complete
13:24:16.247 - pool-1-thread-1 2 complete
13:24:17.247 - pool-1-thread-1 3 complete
13:24:18.248 - pool-1-thread-1 4 complete
13:24:19.248 - pool-1-thread-1 5 complete
13:24:20.248 - pool-1-thread-1 6 complete
13:24:21.248 - pool-1-thread-1 7 complete
13:24:22.249 - pool-1-thread-1 8 complete
13:24:23.249 - pool-1-thread-1 9 complete
```

Comment: Notice: This solution will make the number of worker threads no more than `corePoolSize`